# Magento One Page Checkout Shipping Method Not Loading in Progress Bar

Tags: magento, checkout

I am facing some problem in Magento progress bar. In this i am using Magento 1.9 on checkout page when user fill shipping & billing information then after click continue user can see Both Shipping & Billing in Progress Bar. But when user select Shipping method / Payment Method user unable to see Selected Shipping & Payment Method on Right Progress Bar.

what i did:

1. I already check checkout.xml and opcheckout.js
2. i already replace checkout.xml & opcheckout.js code with fresh downloaded magento.
3. Flush Cache indexing
4. i already test path of progress files in checkout.xml
   and

under checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml

$this->getCheckout()->getStepData('shipping_method', 'complete')

above syntax return null so code to show shipping method not working in progress bar.

if any one has any idea please ping me.

Thanks

Comment: have you enable shipping method in the admin panel ?

Comment: also please enable log and check your system.log what error you get when you try to move to the shipping method section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install the best firefox add-on, Firebug. 
You can see,track,manipulate ajax requests and response there. 
It will show you the response of the ajax requests and you can solute the problem easily.

Cheers.!

Comment: In this shipping address was not working also then what I did I just add    this.reload(shipping) in opcheckout.js then it starts loading I did same with shipping method what I did this.reload(shippingmethod) but instead of showing data it hides shipping method block. When this.reload(shippingmethod) this just hide right shipping method block. Please suggest..

Comment: and under firebug i can see :
xxx.com/checkout/onepage/progress/?prevStep=shippingmethod

returning NULL value

http://prntscr.com/7q9fja

Please check this screenshot.